# Is this bitwise conversion safe?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, signed, unsigned-integer

I have a situation where I need to pack 16 bits into a 64-bit number and later read them back as a signed integer in the range [ -32768, 32768 ).  The method I have chosen for this is to compute the number as a signed 16-bit int, immediately cast it to an unsigned 16-bit int, and then upcast this to a 64-bit unsigned int before performing the proper bit shift to get the critical 16 bits into the proper place.

Here is the pseudo-code to create the bit-packed arrangement:

```
Given int x, y such that x - y >= -32768 and y - x < 32768;
const int MASK_POS = 45;
const unsigned short int u_s = x - y;
unsigned long long int ull_s = u_s;
ull_s <<= MASK_POS;
```

Here is the pseudo-code to extract the difference in the original numbers:

```
Given unsigned long long int ull_s with 16 bits encoding a signed integer in the 46th through 61st bits;
const unsigned short int u_s = ((ulls >> MASK_POS) & 0xffff);
const short int s_s = u_s;
const int difference_x_and_y = s_s;
```

This seems to me like a reasonable way to package a signed integer and extract it.  I'm wary of platform-specific behavior when performing bit shifts on negative integers, but I think that converting to the unsigned form of the same number of bits prior to upgrading the number of overall bits in the number, and in reverse extracting the unsigned integer of the desired bit length before converting to a signed integer of equal size, will be safe.

(In case anyone is curious, there will be a LOT going on in the other 48 bits of this 64-bit unsigned integer that stuff ends up in--from the high three bits to the low 31 and the middle 14, everything has been parsed out.  I can certainly write some unit tests to ensure that this behavior holds on whatever architecture, but if anyone can see a flaw now that's better to know in advance.)

Comment: Note: You can save yourself some typing (and some exceedingly rare potential nastiness if, for example,  `short`'s not 16 bits) with [Fixed Width Integers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer). Instead of `const unsigned short int` you get `const uint16_t` and a compiler error if the type's not supported on the target platform.

Comment: If you require 16-bit and 64-bit integers, you should use the standard `uint16_t`, `uint64_t`, etc.

Comment: I'm often surprised by what's actually undefined behaviour, but if this is evil, I have a lot of code to fix.

Comment: The logic looks perfectly fine. The conversions to unsigned before packing and after unpacking avoid any issues with platform-specific behavior when shifting negatives. Just be careful masking and casting explicitly on unpack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're doing is perfectly fine. Since C++20, signed integers are required to have two's complement representation, and all signed/unsigned conversions are well-defined, and equivalent to `std::bit_cast`. Even before that, any implementation you care about would behave in this way.

However, it would probably be better if you used fixed-width types like `std::uint16_t` since your code heavily relies on a specific width.

```cpp
struct quad {
    std::int16_t x, y, z, w;
};

inline std::uint64_t pack(quad q) {
    // Two-step conversion to std::uint16_t -> std::uint64_t
    // to avoid a sign extension when going directly to std::uint64_t.
    // Alternatively, mask each operand with 0xffff.
    return std::uint64_t{std::uint16_t(q.x)} <<  0
         | std::uint64_t{std::uint16_t(q.y)} << 16
         | std::uint64_t{std::uint16_t(q.z)} << 32
         | std::uint64_t{std::uint16_t(q.w)} << 48;
    // alternatively, if you don't care about relying on
    // platform endianness ...
    return std::bit_cast<std::uint64_t>(q); // note: only works if quad is unpadded
}

inline quad unpack(std::uint64_t x) {
    // just let implicit conversions do their thing
    return { x >> 0, x >> 16, x >> 32, x >> 48 };
    // once again, alternatively ...
    return std::bit_cast<quad>(x);
}
```

You can pack integers like this, but it begs the question why you couldn't just use a `struct` like `quad` directly.
No sane compiler is going to add padding to `quad`, and you could make sure of it with

```cpp
static_assert(sizeof(quad) == sizeof(std::uint64_t));
```

The compiler also isn't allowed to reorder the members of `quad`, so for all intents and purposes, you could just bundle integers up in `quad` instead of packing them into an integer.

Comment: Thanks very much, also @user4581301 and nielsen for similar suggestions.  I will migrate to intXX_t and uintXX_t.  The reason that this is not a struct is that, like I said, there is a LOT of other stuff going on in this 64-bit "thing." The rough process is:
- Read the high three bits and choose which of 7-8 "modes" the low 61 bits should then be read in.  We're already out of struct/union land.
- Different modes will read the low 61 bits in chunks of 61, 31/14/16, 31/10/10/5/5, 31/23/7, 40/21.  Yeah, it's pretty nuts but this is GPU memory bandwidth optimization.

Comment: @doug that's a good idea, I didn't want to go down that road initially because it relies on platform endianness, but that looks to be no issue in this case. I've added it to the answer now.

Comment: @dscerutti Why don't you use bit fields for this task?